# State variable-Cucumber - Ruby -Regular expressions

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am a newbie to Cucumber-Ruby. After defining the scenario, I executed the test in the terminal and cucumber suggested the snippet as follows :

> > **Then**("Show All button should be enabled") **do**
> >
> > pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
> >
> > **end**
> >
> > **Then**("Show All button should be disabled") **do**
> >
> > pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
> >
> > **end**

I changed the code as below

> > **Then**("Show All button should be (enabled|disabled)") **do** |state|
> >
> > puts(state)
> >
> > **end**

But even after that when I execute the test using the terminal I receives the suggestion to add the snippet.

When I changed the code as below it worked

> > **Then**(/^Show All button should be (enabled|disabled)$/) **do** |state|
> >
> > puts(state)
> >
> > **end**

Can someone help me describing the difference between the codes?

**USING**

Ruby  : ruby 2.3.3p222
Cucumber : 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber compares the argument passed to `Then` against scenario titles using case-equal aka triple-equal. That said, for the scenario title `"Foo Bar"` and the snippet `Then something do`, it executes

```
something === "Foo Bar"
```

For strings, triple-equal is aliased to `==` and since `"Show ... (enabled|disabled)"` string is not equal to `"Show ... enabled"` nor to `"Show ... disabled"`, nothing is matched.

OTOH, when you change the argument to `Regexp`, it *matches*:

```
/^Show ... (enabled|disabled)$/ === "Show ... enabled"
#⇒ true
```

That is why the latter snippet effectively works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

When I execute the test in the terminal, cucumber provides me the snippet in string formats, but I have seen for some others the snippet in regular expression format. How can I get cucumber to default to regular expression snippets?

I have added the version am using.

Comment: I have no idea, I never worked with `Cucumber`. I would suggest you to read docs or ask another question on SO.