# Getting Cucumber snippet in String format Not Regular Exp in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

When I execute the test in the terminal, cucumber provides me the snippet in string formats, but I have seen for some others the snippet in regular expression format.
 How can I get cucumber to default to regular expression snippets?

**Output I received:**

```
Then("Show All button should be enabled") do

pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

end
```

**Instead of:**

```
Then (/^Show All button should be enabled$/) do

pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

end
```

**Using:**

Ruby: ruby 2.3.3p222 
Cucumber: 3.1.0

Comment: Any specific reason, why you want in Regex Format ? String format looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal `Then(/^Show (.*)/) do |what|`  covers _all_ the tests starting with `Show` and one might use caught matches as block parameters.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal please refer this URL for the reason

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850727/state-variable-cucumber-ruby-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the newer version of Cucumber, there is no option for regex output and started providing cucumber-expressions. The default transformations available are documented below

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/731